# Surface integral of vector subspace

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, integration

Consider the following vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_4$ in $\mathbb R^5$, $t\in \mathbb R$.

$\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\0\\2\\t\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Let $M=\mathrm{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_4)$.

How can I determine the surface area of $B=\{\lambda_1v_1+\dots\lambda_4v_4|\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_4 \in [0,1]\}$?

For which $t$ does the surface area get maximal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the surface area? The set is a 4-dimensional parallelotope living in a 5-dimensional space. Do you mean the 4-d volume of that set? Or do you mean the 3-d volume of the border of the parallelotope when considered as subset of a 4-d hyperplane (this border consists of 8 parallelepipeds)?

Comment: It should be generalized version of the 2-dimensional case $|a\times b|$